# Xamarin Android Http

Tags: android, http, xamarin.android

I`ve creating an Xamarin.Android project which is doing alot in background. To handle background operations I am using android Service class.

I have experienced wrong behaviour about sending http requests. When the phone is not touched then service is still running as I see in my logs but HttpClient throws exception while trying to use PostAsync() method with message:

> An error occurred while sending the request

When the phone is unlocked or user is in application then requests works fine.

Is it something with Android management?

Comment: Can you post what your `Service` class looks like?  Are you using an `IntentService` or a regular `Service`?